# Sum displayed value of multiple checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a scipt that when I select a checkbox it display the value, but if I check multiple checkbox it display like this

> 1,2,3

I need the script to sum it.

```
function checkbox() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('PreiaBani');
  var checkboxesChecked = [];
  // loop over them all
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("show").value = checkboxesChecked;

}
```

How to get the sum instead of `1,2,3` ?

Comment: you are assigning the array "checkboxesChecked" that contains 1,2,3 that how your code should work

Comment: Now the result is 010203 instead of 1+2+3

Comment: can u give ur html plz

Comment: can show the result for the checkboxesChecked

Comment: The downvotes might have come from not including a small amount of HTML along with the JS. As it may contain more information

Comment: @evolutionxbox This question don't need HTML to be replied. That's a bad downvote.

Comment: @R3tep I agree. SO users on this tag are quick to downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the sum you can use `reduce` method.

Like:

```js
document.getElementById("show").value = checkboxesChecked.reduce((a, b) => a + +b, 0)
```

Comment: Not working, in this way the result is 010203 instead of 6 (1+2+3)

Comment: @PirjolNelu You have this result because your array contain `strings`. You can format to integer with `+`. See my updated code.

Comment: Thanks alot!! 1 more question, why i got voted -2 on this post? :(

Comment: @PirjolNelu I don't know, Users in stack overflow can downvote for anything. Wrong format code, the question contains "Thanks", You can found a good guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see the best way to ask a question

Comment: what the result of array checkboxesChecked

Comment: @Mohammed_Alreai The array `checkboxesChecked` contains all checked value of the inputs with the name `PreiaBani`

Comment: i kow what type of value is number

Comment: The inputs return value as string. So like Pirjol say in this question. `checkboxesChecked` is equal to `["01", "02", "03"]`

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById("show").value = checkboxesChecked.reduce((acc,item)=>acc+item,0)

```js
  const el= [1,2,3].reduce((acc,item)=>acc+item,0);
  console.log(el)
```

Comment: You're forgetting that the data is coming from an input, which will be a string.

Comment: It’s not my question. I just read the code already provided which shows `.value` being added to the array.

Comment: is data that coming string

Comment: The value property will provide a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement